# Симуляция клика по html кнопке в Java приложении

Tags: javascript, java, html, парсер

Есть ли способ, желательно через Jsoup, чтобы подключиться к документу, после клика по кнопке. Если есть какие-то другие способы, прошу рассказать

Занимаюсь парсингом файлообменника, и нужно получить ссылку на скачивание файла по нажатии на кнопку

Вопрос закрыт. [Решение здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/532494/206322)

Comment: Если нужной вам информации нет в загруженном HTML коде и она добавляется на страницу отдельным javascript запросом, то с JSOUP сделать это нельзя. Т.е. эмулировать нажатия - невозможно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я слышал, что в `java` встроен движок `javascript`. Думаю можно как-то все-таки хотя бы без помощи `jsoup` сделать

Comment: Без JSOUP есть какой-то `Silinium web driver` вроде он должен такое уметь. Ну или попробовать отследить в браузере запрос при нажатии кнопки и эмулировать его задав заголовки и прочие его параметры.

Answer (score 1):

(JavaFX) Попробуйте MouseEvent отправить в сторону WebView с координатами кнопки.
Это не Jsoup, но в самом крайнем случае заработает.

```
MouseEvent myMouseEvent = new MouseEvent(null, null, MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, targetX, targetY, screenX, screenY, MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1,
                false, false, false, false,
                true, false, false,
                false, false, false, new PickResult(targetNode,targetX,targetY));

targetNode.fireEvent(myMouseEvent);
```

Comment: Да, я думал о простом кликере. Ладно, как буду делать проект, попробую, спасибо

Comment: @Herrgott Ну что получилось ? Просто у меня аналогичная проблема

Comment: @andrey да, `Headless browser` [ссылка на мой вопрос и список браузеров](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/532494/206322)

Comment: Вот спасибо, выручили!