# Парсинг сайта на Java после всех манипуляций с javascript

Tags: java, парсер

Можно ли каким-нибудь образом спарсить всю страницу так, чтобы все элементы создаваемые/изменяемые `javascript`'ом были видны после загрузки страницы? И была возможность запускать эти скрипты с параметрами. Объясню, допустим есть на сайте текстовое поле с `id="itemname"` и кнопка с `id="submit"`. Я к примеру пишу

```
Element field = getElementById("itemname");
Element button =getElementById("submit ");
field.setText("Кофта");
button.press();
```

И он мне выводит `javascript` генерированный документ. 
То есть это тоже самое как я например зашёл в интернет магазин, в поле поиск (С id itemname) написал "Кофта" и нажал кнопку (С id submit)

Создавать `WebView` и по координатам кликать мне кажется не правильное решение. Ещё где-то видел библиотеку (Не помню как она называется, вроде начинается на 'S'), но мне кажется - это не то, что нужно мне.

Либо авторизация в всплывающем окне то же по такому же принципу без протокола `:javascript`

Если кто-то не понял, например. Я пишу программу на Java, которая будет уведомлять меня в трее Windows что на мой `ruSO` пришел новый ответ. Новый ответ должен парситься из значка вверху сайта (Если нету пустой, если есть то добавляется новый класс к DOMу значка --не знаю как сделано на этом сайте, все примерно--). Но чтобы узнать есть ли у меня сообщения, программа должна скормить серверу мой логин и пароль через JS, а после, в отрендеренной странице, найти те самые значки.

Comment: Вам нужен phantomjs или аналог. Им точно можно управлять через selenium, и, возможно, даже напрямую.

Comment: У SO есть api - надо им и пользоваться. К тому же, чтобы узнать об ответах, даже не надо быть залогиненным.

Comment: @qwertiy мне не для `SO` надо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То что я искал называется `Headless browser`, то есть браузер без визуализации. Для [java](/questions/tagged/java) есть `htmlunit`. [Ссылка на список "Безглавых браузеров" на enSo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814929/6119618)

Answer (score 6):

То, что вы ищете, называется [Selenium WebDriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#java). Ваш пример с "Кофтой" будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.example.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("itemname")).sendKeys("Кофта");
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
```

Comment: У меня не получилось использовать `WebDriver` Firefox, т.к. он у меня не установлен. В `htmlunit` автономно все работает

Answer (score 3):

У меня на библиотеке JSOUP все получилось:

```
String url = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login";
    String login = "mylogin@sobaka.gav";
    String password = "password";

    // Вот и вся авторизация....
    Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(url);
    conn.data("email", login);
    conn.data("password", password);

    Document doc = conn.userAgent("Mazilla i t.d.").post();
    Elements net_items = doc.getElementsByClass("unread-count");
    String mess_and_rep  = net_items.text();
    System.out.println(mess_and_rep);
    //Получился результат: +10
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете в `WebView` скормить `javascript` после загрузки страницы. К примеру, если хотите заполнить Ваше поле `id="itemname"`:

```
String itemname= "Кофта";
webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('itemname').value = '"+itemname+"';");
```

Аналогично и для всего остального, пишете что необходимо и в `webview.loadUrl("javascript:...`

Comment: А не подскажете для обычной `Java` как такое сделать?

Comment: И как мне сделать программный "клик" по кнопке с целью отправить данные для обработки?

Comment: `loadUrl` только для UI потока :(